# REGEXP_SUBSTR - how to get special characters after specific pattern?

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have such a `column`:

```
{"abcVersion" : "1.2.3.4", https://klmno.com:5678/def", "xyzVersion" : "6.7.8.9"}
```

I now would like to get the `numbers` and `.` after the pattern `xyzVersion" : "` in order to get `6.7.8.9` as `result`.
I tried this:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '\d+[^a-z"]+') as result
```

Which obviously gives back `1.2.3.4`. I do not want to specify the position with the arguments within the brackets but want to get the result specifically after the pattern mentioned above.

How could I do this?

Comment: is that a string  or json?

Comment: Datatype is CLOB.

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '([0-9.]+)"}$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) ` will be enough?

Comment: Or, `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '"xyzVersion" : "([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as result`?

Comment: The second one works out. Thanks a lot! Maybe you could also answer my question and maybe state what the arguments in your statement mean? :-)

Comment: You didn't answer Ghost Ops's question. Is that string supposed to be JSON? The data type is CLOB, fine; that is not what you were asked. If it is a JSON (it most definitely is in the example you gave), you should use JSON-specific functions, not regular expression functions. Unless your Oracle version is too old (11.2 or older) - JSON support was added in Oracle 12.1. So, also - what is your Oracle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '"xyzVersion" : "([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as result
```

Notes:

- `"xyzVersion" : "([^"]+)"` matches `"xyzVersion" : "`, then captures one or more chars other than `"` into Group 1 and then matches a `"`
- The last `1` argument tells `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to only return the capturing group 1 value (the first `1` is the position to start searching from and the second `1` tells to match the first occurrence).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`(`TO_CHAR()` conversion might be added in order to convert CLOB to an ordinary string) such as

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*xyzVersion" : )"(.*)("})','\2')) AS result
  FROM t     

RESULT
-------
6.7.8.9
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7f503507414320a07de3b53b7c6e99de)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, but in my case this one did not work out but extracted the whole string in my column...

Comment: you're welcome @Tobitor , can you share the case for which the expression doesn't work properly ..?